# Android java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved

Tags: android

This code doesn't work:

```
URL         url   = new URL( xmlPath );
InputSource input = new InputSource( url.openStream() );
```

all the time, resulting in an UnknownHostException, even when the host exists, has been hit successfully using the same code if from a different development host (machine), and also from a browser.

I'm probably out of line asking this question again, a repeat of [Android java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved (strategy question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293659/android-java-net-unknownhostexception-host-is-unresolved-strategy-question). The forum software would not allow me to comment on the unsatisfactory answer to that question (in order to solicit more attention to the solution I ultimately found). Perhaps I'm not popular enough yet to be given that privilege. In the meantime, I'm essentially re-posting the question and a different answer.

Basically, I accept that maybe the Android device has a hard time with DNS under certain circumstances, but I've tried, for example the anddev.org example of how to use the SAX parser, and it worked on one machine I have and not on another.

Edit:
As noted, I know a working answer and will post it.

I am a) asking a question (that's already been asked and unsuccessfully answered) and b) answering it for the benefit of those for whom my answer will be useful.

Comment: No clue whether you are asking a question?  Making a comment?  Or plan to answer your own question... please clarify or the voting to close will commence.

Comment: So, yeah, I tried the solution to the first link above--calling InetAddress.getByName( url ), but even doing it several times, it never "awakened" anything in the device's ability to resolve names or get them resolved--wish I knew, obviously, exactly what's wrong, but it appears to be an Android-only problem!

Comment: @Nix: I answered your threat in an edit of my question. Apparently, form is more important in this forum than substance? If you don't want my answer, then toss away, mate! I'm just doing my best to give back to the next poor schmuck who, like me, wasted his morning trying to solve this really simple, yet totally blocking, problem.

Comment: maybe this should be a community wiki if you are asking a question and answering it all in 1 shot.

Comment: I read your question, and now see your answer, but I they don't make sense.    We shouldn't have to click around to A) Understand the question you are asking Or B) to understand your answer.

Comment: @@Ryan Conrad: I hadn't planned on it. I only wanted to comment on an answer to a question that had not worked hoping for more thought. As the forum software wouldn't let me do it (inexplicably), I re-posted the question which I thought to be an iffy thing to do. Then, I ended up spending the morning outside the forum until I found the answer. And hey, I thought, why don't I give back to stackoverflow in case someone else would benefit? (Silly me.)

Comment: @ (latest) Nix: Yes, I totally agree and I hope I've rewritten it clear enough to be useful.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The answer is devilishly simple: remove, then re-create your AVD (virtual device/emulator) in Eclipse. It worked for me--first time.

Comment: Worked for me too. I think my issue was down to me creating the AVD before I had downloaded the extra components to get the SDK/Eclipse running properly on a 64-bit Fedora platform.

Comment: I found this thread because I was having the exact same issue with an actual device!  I finally figured out that the device had somehow found its way to airplane mode, lol.  So I guess the lesson here would be to test your internet connectivity on the device if having this problem :)

Comment: Simply restarting the virtual device worked for me. I wish I had tried that after ~2 hours of debugging!

Comment: I spent 3 hours trying to fix or get value ,system restart and a new AVD-Emulator start , did fix the problem, thanks. saved the day

Answer (score 55):

I been follow the steps above but still try no luck, finally i just realize my app did not allow to go outside internet in the emulator. So just add users permissions in your manifest file. Done! Thanks to jozsi see http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device

1. android.permission.INTERNET
2. android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
3. android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: i had not added "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />"

Answer (score 14):

In my case I was downloading an XML file from a URL on my phone but was having the issue describe in this thread.

for fixing it, I not only needed to have the regular internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But I also needed

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

As a suggestion to see if your device may need the same thing, try navigating to the URL in your phone's browser to see if prompts about needing SD Card or something.

Hope that helps others.

Comment: Hahaha, I spent a day trying to debug something that gives an error like this, but didn't realize that I didn't give it Internet permission. Android doesn't even give a warning saying that it doesn't have permission.

Answer (score 13):

I have seen this on a phone as well (while doing USB debugging). The solution was to disable WiFi, and re-enable it.

Comment: This was the solution for me.  After trying all the other alternatives, I went into my settings and turned off WiFi, then turned it back on.  Back into the app, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

It work's for me by adding user's permission for Internet in `AndroidMenifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case the problem was elsewhere. I had to:

- add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
- setup a proxy server on my emulator : `Emulator > settings > wireless and network > Mobile Networks > Access Point Name > "the access point you have ;)"`. Here you can set all the proxy port url and login/pass you want.

**AND**

- Call my network operation in a separate thread. The easy way was to **implement an AsynchTask.**

I found the solution here:

[HTTP doesn't work in Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277734/http-doesnt-work-in-android-emulator)

> " This exception is there for a reason. Network activity can take time,
>   performing networking on the main thread, which is the same thread
>   that responsible for updating the UI, would freeze the thread until
>   the networking is done (this is what happens on every thread, but when
>   it's performed on a dedicated thread, it's ok). In Android, if the
>   UI-thread isn't active for 5 seconds, it will show the Application is
>   not responsive, Do you want to close it? dialog. "

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable internet in your emulator.

- Open emulator
- Press menu button and open "settings"
- Open "wireles and network"
- Open "Mobile Networks"
- Check on "Data enable"

Now test your application again.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get rid of the emulator "UnknownHostExceptions" - and the emulator's browser wouldn't get a connection either. Tried all suggestions I could find at stack overflow and everywhere else.

Finally I deleted my AVD, shut down Eclipse, and then created the AVD via the command line. Then launched it via command line with the -dns-server 8.8.8.8. (on my Mac: ./emulator -avd Google-8 -dns-server 8.8.8.8) It finally worked!

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much Russ. I'm glad you persisted. I had spent the best part of an hour reading all kinds of possible fixes to this error. Just for anyone else stumbling across this thread, i'll briefly recap here:
-Check Internet uses permission is in the manifest
-Catching the exception (pointless)
-Changing firewall settings on your OS
-Share connection (windows only)
And a load of other stuff

My fix took a little more than yours, but not much.
After reading your post, I closed and destroyed all emulators. Then I noticed that when I moused over the run button (green circle with white arrow) it said the program was already running, even though no AVDs (emulators) existed! Anyway, restarted eclipse, created a AVD and ran it and Bob was my father's brother. Nothing to do with my code or setup at all.

I found this afterwards. It may well achieve the same thing but I can't vouch for it unless the problem reoccurs.
http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2011/02/stopping-android-applications-already.html
Another trick that /may/ achieve the same result is tick "wipe user data" in Run Configurations, Target tab.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was when sharing the internet from the computer via WIFI, after ethernet connection was lost and reconnected I couldn't achieve connection on the phone. This was fixed by restarting internet sharing on computer.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using host name based URL with HttpURLConnection. However, using an IP based url, resolved the issue. I also deleted/recreated the AVD but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I just restart the AVD and add the User Permission then it works.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 2):

issue resolved

run cd C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools

run android list avd in cmd returns list of ur availabe avd.... in my case its Myabc_avd

run emulator @Myabc_avd -dns-server 8.8.8.8 in cmd ...avd will show avd 
go to avd's browser and type www.google.com will show google page.
u can now access browser using hostname like myfrstapp.com

if all go well then u can run ur project using eclipse but make sure it is running in avd which is running from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have just restarted the Emulator and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**It's so simple.** No need of Restart eclipse OR delete and creating Emulator, you just need to follow the steps given below:

1. Right Click on your project
2. Click "**Run as**"
3. Click "**Run configuration**"
4. Window will get opened
5. In left panel select your project run configuration
6. Then in right panel open "**Target**" tab
7. Scroll down
8. You will get an option at bottom called "**Additional Emulator Command Line Arguments**"
9. Put "**-dns-server 8.8.8.8**" these values (**without double quotes**) in text box.

That's it...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when I had started the emulator while I was logged on to a VPN. Logging off the VPN had no effect until I quit the emulator and restarted. It is easy to test if your emulator is not resolving names correctly - just go to the **emulator** browser and type in a website hostname.

Answer (score 0):

- Got to Device manager
- select emulator
- click Cold Boot now
- run selected emulator

Answer (score -1):

Please try rebooting the emulator.