# firewall problem in android

Tags: android

Hi Friends
reason of **Kerio WinRoute firewall** install in server i cant start internet in android. i   want to develop one application in which i get data from internet.
my problem is connection with internet.
when i run project this kind of error accure.
`06-29 10:37:28.207: WARN/System.err(384): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/top-30-android-games.jpg` (**Permission denied**)
in this project, retrieve file from website,all code are working good but i think this is problem of internet access. 
 can anyone help me

Comment: Nik, your question doesn't make any sense, could you rephrase it and add more information?

Comment: if you have a firewall issue from your local router, simply disable wifi.  now you're on your carrier's network, which presumably, won't have a firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is related to your question:
[problem to store data into sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506225/problem-to-store-data-into-sdcard)

I will repeat here that you need permission in your manifest to write to sd card. The error is not related to any firewall...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

---

**EDIT**

I have noticed that you are using emulator for testing.
Have you specified in your AVD device the usage of sd card? If not you shoud edit your device from AVD manager. You must specify size of sd card (at least 8 MB)

Comment: i use 2.2 avd and 1000 mib specified.

Answer (score -1):

Kerio Winroute firewall has no ability to identify wich application sends requests to the internet. It can only restrict access based on predefined rules.
If you don't mean an emulator ant if you talking abot connection your android phone to the internet using wi-fi. Please make sure that your phone has an ip address and this address has an access to the internet access in kerio rulesets.
If your problem will not solved by this advice - please let me know. I have an experience in winroute configuration.