# Error in http connection

Tags: android

hi I am trying to fetch data from link as given below

```
 http://abovestress.com/app_stress/fetch_all_detail.php?task=fetchtimefromdateanduserid&track_date=2011-08-09&tracker_user_id=374
```

but I can't get result my code is here

```
package com.JsonDemo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class JsonDemoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ArrayList<String> fetchsosfromID = new ArrayList<String>();
    String result = "";
    InputStream is = null;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("track_date","2011-08-09"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tracker_user_id",""+374));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://abovestress.com/app_stress/fetch_all_detail.php?task=fetchtimefromdateanduserid&");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.v("log_tag", "Append String " + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // parse json data
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            fetchsosfromID.add(json_data.getString("track_time"));
            Log.v("log_tag", "daily_data " + fetchsosfromID);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

and error comes like this

```
08-09 17:29:01.315: ERROR/log_tag(2291): Error in http connection java.net.UnknownHostException: abovestress.com
08-09 17:29:01.315: ERROR/log_tag(2291): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 17:29:01.345: ERROR/log_tag(2291): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

manifiest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.JsonDemo"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".JsonDemoActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put permission tag put of application tag...

Answer (score 4):

You've definitely added the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

in your manifest, right?

**Edit:** Your `<uses-permission>` is in the wrong place. It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.JsonDemo"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".JsonDemoActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It is a manifest problem. the `<uses-permission>` should be outside the `<application>` tag.

Comment: @Jignesh Ansodariya: Could you please stop using twenty thousand dots? And if you comment hasn't enough characters, than simple form a sentence. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you get points to a name resolution problem (getting abovestress.com ip address from DNS server). That is probably because your network is down.

A simple snippet to check if a network connection is up, where `Context ctx` is you Activity context:

```
public boolean checkConnection(Context ctx) {
  ConnectivityManager conMgr =  
     (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (i == null)
      return false;
    if (!i.isConnected())
      return false;
    if (!i.isAvailable())
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

EDIT:

if network in not your problem, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293659/android-java-net-unknownhostexception-host-is-unresolved-strategy-question) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514398/android-java-net-unknownhostexception-host-is-unresolved)

you may need to add (besides `android.permission.INTERNET`) other permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

and/or:

```
try {
  InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(URLName);
} catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
// ... actually using URL
```

EDIT 2: AND, as noted by others, `uses-permission` element goes inside `manifest` element, not `application` element

Comment: No, network is ok because other applications are working on Json

Comment: ok, take a look at my edited answer for possible alternatives to workaround hostname resolution problems