# Error with Android XML reader

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML parser that works correctly, but if the User is connected to a network that are not browsing the app breaks. To put a function to detect whether or not the User is connected, but the problem mentioned above, the User would be connected but no browsing.

My code follows in full:

```
public void chamaParser(){
    Boolean conected = Conectado(this);
    if(conected == true){
        new DoInBackground().execute();
    } else {
        mPullRefreshListViewRSS.onRefreshComplete();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.this)
                .setTitle("Alerta!")
                .setMessage("Não foi possível estabelecer uma conexão com a Internet, verifique sua rede ou tente novamente mais tarde.")
                .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
        }).show();
    }
}

public void do_update() {
    RssParser.parse();
}

public static boolean Conectado(Context context) {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String LogSync = null;
        String LogToUserTitle = null;
        if (cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected()) {
            LogSync += "\nConectado a Internet 3G ";
            LogToUserTitle += "Conectado a Internet 3G ";
            return true;
        } else if(cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()) {
            LogSync += "\nConectado a Internet WIFI ";
            LogToUserTitle += "Conectado a Internet WIFI ";
            return true;
        } else {
            LogSync += "\nNão possui conexão com a internet ";
            LogToUserTitle += "Não possui conexão com a internet ";
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

private class DoInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.this, "", "Carregando...", true);
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.this, "", "Carregando...", true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    mPullRefreshListViewRSS.onRefreshComplete();
                    DoInBackground.this.cancel(true);
                    // finish();
                }
        });
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) { 
        PodcastAdapterRSS.topBarRSS=true;

        do_update(); 
        return null; 
    }
```

Parser XML:

```
public class RssParser {

    public static void parse() {
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.xxxx.com.br/feed/");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc;
                doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList itemLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
                arrays.Title = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
                arrays.Link = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
                arrays.Description = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
                // arrays.PodcastMedia = new String[itemLst.getLength()];

                for(int i=0; i < itemLst.getLength(); i++){

                    Node item = itemLst.item(i);
                    if(item.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                        Element ielem = (Element)item;
                        NodeList title = ielem.getElementsByTagName("title");
                        NodeList link = ielem.getElementsByTagName("link");
                        //NodeList description = ielem.getElementsByTagName("description"); 
                        NodeList content = ielem.getElementsByTagName("description");
                        //   NodeList media = ielem.getElementsByTagName("media:content");

                        //    String mediaurl = media.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("url").getNodeValue();

                          arrays.Title[i] = title.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                          arrays.Link[i] = link.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                          arrays.Description[i] = content.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DOMException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Log Cat:

> 07-30 15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: www.xxxx.com.br 07-30
>   15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:508) 07-30
>   15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:296) 07-30
>   15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:258) 07-30
>   15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):    at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:69)
>   07-30 15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:48)
>   07-30 15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
>   07-30 15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
>   07-30 15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
>   07-30 15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
>   07-30 15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
>   07-30 15:20:48.319: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:726)
>   07-30 15:20:48.329: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   tabbar.rss.RssParser.parse(RssParser.java:30) 07-30 15:20:48.329:
>   W/System.err(10997):  at
>   tabbar.rss.PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.do_update(PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.java:91)
>   07-30 15:20:48.329: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   tabbar.rss.PullToRefreshListActivityRSS$DoInBackground.doInBackground(PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.java:205)
>   07-30 15:20:48.329: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   tabbar.rss.PullToRefreshListActivityRSS$DoInBackground.doInBackground(PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.java:1)
>   07-30 15:20:48.329: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185) 07-30 15:20:48.329:
>   W/System.err(10997):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>   07-30 15:20:48.329: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 07-30
>   15:20:48.329: W/System.err(10997):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   07-30 15:20:48.329: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   07-30 15:20:48.329: W/System.err(10997):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019) 07-30 15:20:48.329:
>   W/dalvikvm(10997): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x401fc560) 07-30 15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 07-30 15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 07-30 15:20:48.339:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10997):  at
>   tabbar.rss.PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.populate_listview(PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.java:101)
>   07-30 15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):  at
>   tabbar.rss.PullToRefreshListActivityRSS$DoInBackground.onPostExecute(PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.java:214)
>   07-30 15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):  at
>   tabbar.rss.PullToRefreshListActivityRSS$DoInBackground.onPostExecute(PullToRefreshListActivityRSS.java:1)
>   07-30 15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417) 07-30 15:20:48.339:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10997):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127) 07-30
>   15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
>   07-30 15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-30
>   15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 07-30 15:20:48.339:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10997):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689) 07-30
>   15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-30
>   15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 07-30 15:20:48.339:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10997):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
>   07-30 15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633) 07-30
>   15:20:48.339: E/AndroidRuntime(10997):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If that doesn't work, consult the answers to these two questions:

[Android java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514398/android-java-net-unknownhostexception-host-is-unresolved)

[Android java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved (strategy question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293659/android-java-net-unknownhostexception-host-is-unresolved-strategy-question)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give your asynctask a timeout handler, since you are connected but not downloading anything. Put a timeout for around 3000 - 5000ms

How to create a timeout handler:

[Android - Setting a Timeout for an AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882739/android-setting-a-timeout-for-an-asynctask)

Comment: I did the following:
  do_update();
  try {   DoInBackground.this.get(30000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (TimeoutException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace(); 
         }
               });
works for the problem reported in the post, but I created another when the User has a connection he hopes to put the time in AsyncTask to begin downloading the feed :/

Comment: Okay, you're saying that it worked to prevent your app from breaking, but you created another problem? What is the next problem?